# R question - generate sequence of numbers for a variable in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame that is 298 observations long. One of the variables is totally blank. It has to do with sample_ids. I know that each row is one observation. It's totally fine in this case to have the numbers just go up sequentially. Essentially, I need the variable to count 1:298.

I've tried this seq function but it doesn't work:

```
geology_data$SampleID <- seq(from = 1, to = 298, by = 1)
```

I've also found a similar post on StackOverflow that suggests using the rep function more like this:

```
geology_data$SampleID <- rep(1:ceiling(nrow(geology_data$SampleID)))
```

But this one gives me an error:

Error in ceiling(nrow(geology_data$SampleID)) :
non-numeric argument to mathematical function

When I try to simplify it I get a different error:

```
geology_data$SampleID <- rep(1:nrow(geology_data$SampleID))
```

Error in 1:nrow(geology_data$SampleID) : argument of length 0

Comment: Try `geology_data$SampleID <-1:298`

Comment: The `seq` should have worked for you.  What is the error for that.  with `rep` there is one more argument and that is the reason it failed

Comment: I went back and looked at the seq one:
it does work I'm sorry about that. I counted the rows wrong :/ 
so it turns out this nrow one was safer:
geology_data$SampleID <- seq(1, nrow(geology_data))
this was the error:
Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last option does not work, because geology_data$SampleID is a vector and not a dataframe.

Try either

```
geology_data$SampleID <- seq(1, length(geology_data$SampleID))
```

or

```
geology_data$SampleID <- seq(1, nrow(geology_data))
```

Comment: that worked perfectly thanks so much